# How to import raw CSS as raw text in JS side, generated from Vue components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vue-loader

I'd like to be able to import the whole css file that was generated from Vue components to css/app.[hash].css as raw text from js code.

I.e. I would like to do something like

```
const cssAsRawText = await import("!raw-loader!vue-style-loader!@/App.vue");
```

How is this possible to be done?

I'm using Vue 3 with vue-cli.

Use case: I would like to export static HTML with the same style sheet that is used in Vue app.